# idiomatic expression for a promise that was not delivered

Tags: idioms

I was wondering if there's an idiomatic expression to say that "someone or something did not delivered as promised". Like *The method's promise was cut short* or something similar.

Comment: You could say that it **did not live up to expectations**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The method **fell short of** what had been promised--

"*fall short (of something)
to not reach an amount or standard*"
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+short